# Ant build Android project with dependency lib

Tags: android, ant, shared-libraries

I have two Android projects, one shared library and the app. Now I want to compile the app with dependency to the library. In Eclipse, it works very well. After that, I upload it via git to my repository and trigger Jenkins to build both projects.

My problem is, that the error occurs: "sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:440: ../shared-lib resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project". That's clear, because in Jenkins the jobs are stored different than under Eclipse.

Another problem is, that Eclipse compiled the shared to ".jar" and Ant compiled it to "classes.jar" (is named in sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml).

Comment: I don't quite get the question here. can you also include the ant script (or extract from it) and the way you generated it if any.

Comment: I'm using the build.xml created by Android with **update-project** and my _project.properties_ includes **android.library.reference.1=../shared-lib**. 
Do you want any other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with copy files. The first project builds my `shared-lib.jar`. The other projects (phone and tablet) copy this file (shared-lib.jar) to there `libs`-folder and build correctly. But now I have different `projects.properties`on the server and my dev-client. This one is not checked in into git.

Comment: Could you explain how you used ant or Jenkins to copy the files on the build server? I'm a complete ant newb so don't be afraid to dumb it down. :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239131/ant-build-android-project-with-dependency-lib/9277001#comment11638044_9239303 I used the copy task in ant.

Answer (score 4):

Ant scripts should allow you to include whatever files you need. In your case I will suggest you move the reference to the `shared-lib` to `local.properties` file (this file should also be read by the ant script generated by update-project. Keep the adequate path for jenkins in the repository and modify the file locally for the local built. In the file in the repository you will need to have something like:

```
android.library.reference.1=../classes.jar
```

**EDIT** By the way the suggestion of the second properties file is just because this file is really meant to store location-specific properties.

Comment: What can I do to copy the `classes.jar` to the `libs` folder in my build.xml in the `post-build` enviroment. That would be the smarter way, I think.

Comment: There is an ant copy command that you can see here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html. You, however, can also easily add additional jars to the build paths too. I don't know your level of knowledge of ant, but this should be relatively easy to find in the net too. Write back if you need help in this direction.

Comment: I can try helping you more but after some time, now I need to catch my bus :)

Comment: I can't use copy, because the project.properties has to include `android.library.reference.1=`. Is it possible to change the searchpath in ant? Which is the root for `..` in the file?

Comment: The root should be the directory with `build.xml`. I didn't quite get why copy will not work for you, but if you are sure about it you may just provide different properties files in the jenkins environment and in your local.

Comment: Okay, I tried changing the `project.properties`. At first it seems to work, but after using one class of the shared, a failure occured.

Comment: I think we should find some time we are both available and try to fix it in chat. I really want to try to help you out, especially as you try to develop the right way (in this case using continuous integration).