# Copying files with Ant in Jenkins

Tags: android, ant, jenkins

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239131/ant-build-android-project-with-dependency-lib). I've got the same problem as the original poster, but practically 0 skill with Ant. I tried reading about the [ant copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) but clearly that documentation is not intended for the uninitiated. Can someone tell me how to modify Project A's build setup in ant and Jenkins so that it includes the proper jar files from project B? Copying them to Project A's libs folder is ok.

Also, how would I avoid having separate properties files locally and on the server so that eclipse and jenkins can avoid touching each other but I can still keep everything under source control?

Comment: There's no real way around this from what little experience I have in this area :) Gotta get deep and dirty in the documentation!

Comment: Any chance you could point me to the right spot at least? I find it hard to believe that I have to completely understand everything about Ant to perform a simple copy function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I needed [here](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/samples-ant-copy-task). Adding the copy task prior to the build step ensured that the libraries were found.

To keep the copy paths and local properties from conflicting I use the .classpath file for eclipse builds.

Comment: I'd tried, but it told me I had to wait before I could accept it.